# Cannot plot anything in sagemath

Tags: python, sage

if I try to plot anything in sagemath console using any plotting function (plot, circle,...) I get this error and sagemath shuts down after less than a second.

---

**The error:**

> "Unhandled SIGSEGV: a  segmentation fault occured. This probably
> occured because of *compiled* module has a bug in it and is not
> properly wrapped with sign_on(), sign_off(). Python will now
> terminate."
>
> "/opt/sagemath-9.2/src/bin/sage-python: line 2: 244 segmentation fault
> (core dumped) sage -python "$@" "

---

The only thing I came up with is running the program as administrator, which gave the same result.

Could someone help me?

*Note:* I didn't change any file locations, they are all default

Comment: You may want to report a bug [here](https://trac.sagemath.org/newticket). Be sure to mention how you installed SageMath, what operating system you're using, and any other details that could be relevant.

Comment: Or report this to [the sage-support mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/sage-support) with the information suggested by @Dennis: operating system (and its version) and how Sage was installed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will definitely try.

Comment: trac tickets from SageMath have moved to github. I can see https://github.com/sagemath/sage-windows/issues/57 but the sage-windows repo is archived??